# Trigger build in Jenkins/Hudson using hashtag in commit-message

Tags: build, continuous-integration, hudson, commit-message, continuous-deployment

Is it possible to trigger a Hudson/Jenkins build only when a certain string appears in a commit-message?

For instance, I want to trigger a build that rolls out my application to the dev environment by writing a commit message like:

> MYPROJECT-123 Fixed NPE in MyClass.java **#deploy:DEV**

The general idea is described in this [great talk on Continuos Deployment](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Continuous-Deployment-50-Times-a-Day) but I couldn't find any information on how to do this in Hudson.

I would prefer to have this behavior in Hudson itself and not in an external system like commit-hooks or web-hooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of an out of the box way you can parse the SCM message as part of the trigger.  You have a couple of options that might achieve what you want though

1. Write your own Hudson SCM plugin
2. Chain your jobs together into a build pipeline.  The first job could simply look for that message in the changelog.xml to determine if the next build is triggered or not.

If you are looking at building a pipeline of build jobs, check out the build-pipeline-plugin.  http://www.centrumsystems.com.au/blog/?p=121

Anyone got a more elegant solution??

Cheers,

Geoff

Comment: Thanks Geoff! I was guessing that there was no built-in way to do it. 

1. I looked into extending the SVN-plugin, which already has support for _excluding_ certain commit-messages from triggering a build. So the other way around should not be that hard.

2. Thanks for the hint! I'll definitely give it a try.

Comment: Why not just write a post-commit hook that will trigger the build.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Commit Message Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Commit+Message+Trigger+Plugin), but it had just a 0.1 release.

Maybe the easiest way is to use a version control post commit (or push) trigger to start a Hudson Job. You'd one anyway to automatically start your build.