# How to configure jenkins to build automatically for a particular commit message

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am trying to configure Jenkins for automation process. I want to configure Jenkins to build automatically for a commit with specific message not for all commits, say i want Jenkins to build for a commit message " Completed". I have seen configuration for building automatically when a commit is made to subversion. But it will take build for every commit. I don't need take build for every commit. Can anyone guide me to a good solution??

Comment: a similar question asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281816/trigger-build-in-jenkins-hudson-using-hashtag-in-commit-message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger build in Jenkins/Hudson using hashtag in commit-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281816/trigger-build-in-jenkins-hudson-using-hashtag-in-commit-message)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is to create a post-commit hook in subversion that will parse your commit message and trigger the Jenkins build depending on the message content.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called Commit Message Trigger Plugin. Use it.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Commit+Message+Trigger+Plugin