# How to trigger job with commit message in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to trigger job for each commit but based on commit message pattern or key word matching.
Yes, We have plugin "Commit Message Trigger Plugin" for free style projects alone.
How to achieve this with in pipeline project too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger build in Jenkins/Hudson using hashtag in commit-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281816/trigger-build-in-jenkins-hudson-using-hashtag-in-commit-message)

Answer (score 1):

When we were starting to use pipelines in our company, we had the stash pullrequest builder plug-in which couldn't be used from pipeline as well.

Therefore we used a simple freestyle job to trigger our pipeline build using the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://www.google.de/url?q=https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized%2BTrigger%2BPlugin&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjOhI-ysfPRAhUJVxoKHXDCAIgQFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNGesRhhCKxEHTMjlEwnyvp_adrIwA) to provide the downstream build the git commit to build. Using the Plugin you can also provide custom named parameters with the values of the git plugin environment variables:

> branch=${GIT_BRANCH}

You can find them in the *Environment variables* section of the [Git Plugin wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin).

Edit: Access the provided parameters using the `params` object:

> echo "Branch: ${params.branch}"